# Zend Framework: setting a Zend_Form_Element form field to be required, how do I change the validator used to ensure that the element is not blank

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

When using a `Zend_Form`, the only way to validate that an input is not left blank is to do

```
$element->setRequired(true);
```

If this is not set and the element is blank, it appears to me that validation is not run on the element.

If I do use `setRequired()`, the element is automatically given the standard NotEmpty validator. The thing is that the error message with this validator sucks, "Value is empty, but a non-empty value is required". I want to change this message. At the moment I have done this by changing the `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty` class, but this is a bit hacky.

I would ideally like to be able to use my own class (derived from `Zend_Validate_NotEmpty`) to perform the not empty check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it this way (ZF 1.5):

```
$name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name');
$name->setLabel('Full Name: ')
     ->setRequired(true)
     ->addFilter('StripTags')
     ->addFilter('StringTrim')
     ->addValidator($MyNotEmpty);
```

so, the addValidator() is the interesting part. The Message is set in an "Errormessage File" (to bundle all custom messages in one file):

```
$MyNotEmpty = new Zend_Validate_NotEmpty();
$MyNotEmpty->setMessage($trans->translate('err.IS_EMPTY'),Zend_Validate_NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY);
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

By default, setRequired(true) tells isValid() to add a NonEmpty validation *if one doesn't already exist*. Since this validation doesn't exist until isValid() is called, you can't set the message.

The easiest solution is to simply manually add a NonEmpty validation before isValid() is called and set it's message accordingly.

```
$username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
$username->setRequired(true)
         ->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => 'Empty!')));
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a NotEmpty validator, and add your own message:

```
// In the form class:
$username = $this->createElement('text', 'username');
$username->setRequired();  // Note that this seems to be required!
$username->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array(
    'messages' => array(
        'isEmpty' => 'my localized err msg')));
```

**Note** that the NotEmpty validator doesn't seem to be triggered unless you've also called setRequired() on the element.

In the controller (or wherever), call $form->setTranslator($yourTranslator) to localize the error message when it's printed to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [error message](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.validation.errors).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see [Changing the error message](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.validation.errors/) has no way of changing the message of a specific error. Plus the manual makes it look like like this is a function belonging to Zend_Form, but I get method not found when using it on an instance of Zend_Form.

And example of the useage would be really great.